# Persistent restart

Tags: recovery-mode

Can anyone here help please?

my galaxy tab 2 with jelly Bean 4+ keeps restarting itself. Here is what happens:

1- while it is rebooting itself constantly, i hold the power button. it boots.but stays on only for one minute and starts its rebooting cycle again.

2-i put it on safe mode.the little " safe mode " shows up at a corner.but there is no real change.it doesn't really go into safe mode. All apps remain there and it falls into it's rebooting cycle again after one or tow minutes.

3-i press and hold the right buttons for recovery. The recovery mode comes up. I select factory reset.and then say yes.it brings up some 4-5 new lines up and says I can boot now, which I do. It turns on but again no changes.no reset happens at all.and soon it sinks into its restarting cycle..
So to put it in a nutshell it neither factory-resets nor does it go in safe mode.

All I can do now is what I explained in number 1 above. I turn it on and during that one minute window, before it restarts itself, I bring up boot menu and turn it off.

Now, What can I do?, Without using a computer.I don't have one. 
But if connecting my tablet to a computer is the only way, then how could I do it using a computer?
And I am not a geek.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1)Boot into recovery mode and clear cache.

- Power Down the tablet
- Hold Volume Up button and power button at same time, wait until it starts and release Volume Up button only after you see the menu,
- In this menu only volume key and power key works, so, navigate to , wipe cache partition and press power key, that will select that option and proceed.
  -In new menu , agree to proceed, by selecting OK , using volume key and power key.

2)Boot into recovery mode and Factory Reset.

- Follow same steps as above
- In this menu only volume key and power key works, so, navigate to , Wipe data/ factory reset and press power key, that will select that option and proceed.
  -In new menu , agree to proceed, by selecting OK , using volume key and power key.